# How to Iterate and calculate into rows with adding a new column based on previos column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please help me with solving a problem. In Dataframe I have 250k rows:

Column A with rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6

I want to calculate 1*2, 1*3, 1*4, 1*5, 1*6

I want to add column B with column A with values like this:

The maximum value of Row 1 of column A: = 6

```
Output df
index:column A:    column B:            column c(contains column A index): 
0        1       Max(1*5) = 5             4
1        2       Max(2*5) = 10            4
2        1       Max(1*5) = 5             4
3        4       Max(4*5) = 20            4
4        5       Max(5*5) = 25            4
```

And Give me a precise solution with python with maximum solution speed.
Thanks to all.

Comment: the question is a bit unclear!! why u want 1*2, 1*3, etc.. Kindly post a sample output dataframe as well

Comment: @MehulGupta. this is a sample. Now I write exactly. i have one column with emails. i want to calculate jaro_distance with every emails. and finally which email have larger distance then it will show that the first email has maximum Jaro distance with this email and distance is. I hope you understand

Comment: QUestion is about `pandas`, not about `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).